# ¿Como detectar si se introdujo un caracter o signo?

Tags: c

Estoy haciendo un programa de operaciones con vectores y me ha surgido la duda de como saber si el usuario introdujo una letra, ya que si el usuario la introduce el programa deja de funcionar pero claro necesito hacer operaciones con los números que introduzca el usuario por lo que no podría declarar la variable como char. He estado investigando y leído cosas como convertir char a numerico o al reves con el valor de ASCII pero no me quedo muy claro,Gracias de antemano.

a continuación dejo un ejemplo muy sencillo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main( ) {
  float numero1, numero2, suma;

  printf( "Introduzca un numero" );
  scanf( "%f", &numero1 );
  printf( "Introduzca otro  numero" );
  scanf( "%f", &numero2 );

  suma = numero1 + numero2;

  printf( "%f + %f = %f", numero1, numero2, suma );
  Sleep( 50000 );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copiado de la página de manual:

> #### scanf( )
>
> #### Valor devuelto
>
> Esta función devuelve el número de elementos de la entrada asignados, que pueden ser menores que los formatos suministrados para conversión, o incluso cero, en el caso de un fallo de  concordancia. Cero indica que, mientras había  caracteres disponibles en la entrada, no ocurrió ninguna asignación; normalmente esto es debido a un carácter de entrada inválido, como un carácter alfabético para una conversión `%d'.

Pues listo:

```
if( !scanf( "%f", &numero1 ) ) printf( "Error: por favor, introduzca un nnmero\n" );
```

Comment: gracias porque si que me funciona el problema que tengo que en vez de un if puse while porque quiero que revise esa condición hasta que el usuario meta un numero pero se repite el bucle infinitamente

Comment: @SergioAtienza Si tienes nuevos problemas, publica otra nueva pregunta. No edites esta, porque entonces perderá el hilo entre el título, la pregunta y la respuesta. Seguro que alguien estará encantado de ayudarte :-)